# Will ROS2 work on Apple Silicon Macs?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, ros2, macosx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apple is soon to release new Macs based on Arm processors (known as Apple Silicon). How might this affect the support for ROS2 on MacOS? Is this a good or a bad thing for ROS2 on Mac?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364340/will-ros2-work-on-apple-silicon-macs?/) by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on ROS Answers with karma: 501 on 2020-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aeltawil](https://answers.ros.org/users/65124/aeltawil/) on 2020-12-10**:
Do you have an update regarding this topic? Do you someone who was successfully get ROS2 to work on any apple silicon Mac?

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-12-14**:
I'd be keen to find out whether anyone has tested this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Other than the CPU architecture, not much will change wrt how software is typically distributed on macos. I believe that's the limiting factor for ROS 2 (and ROS 1 actually).

ROS 2 has support for OSX (it's a Tier 1 supported platform), but the UX is not consistent with Linux and Windows IIUC (I don't have a mac, so don't know).

Moving to ARM doesn't really change that. ARM64 is already supported (see *Targeted Platforms* in [REP-2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html)), and "Apple Silicon" is really just that.

Homebrew is a bit of a mess though, and so are the other options. So from-source builds can be involved (to say the least). Conda might have a bigger impact, but I'm not sure what the status of the macos support is.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Py](https://answers.ros.org/users/48264/py/) on 2020-10-29**:
Thanks for the insight!